# Entity Framework Re-adding Existing Database Objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Ok, I will describe this as simply as I can.
For example - I have two tables in a database, Employee & Profile.
Employee has a foreign key for ProfileID so 1 Profile can be assigned to many Employees to determine their access rights, all well and good.

In EF using c# - When Choosing say creating an employee and setting an already existing profile as below, it tries to add the Profile into the database again?

```
using (var ds = new DSEntities())
                {
                    Employee e = new Employee();
                    e.AccessProfile = ds.AccessProfiles.First();
                    ds.Employees.Add(e);
                    ds.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Only the Employee record is new and the Profile is not. Can anyone confirm why it does this?
I can set the Employee.AccessProfileID key directly and just set that to the ds.AccessProfiles.First().AccessProfileID so Im not working with the object and that doesnt try to add it again as its just a ref - but I really dont think that I should have too and I must be missing something, I can select these elements directly as objects but assigning them always results in a database re-add of the profile etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add existing profile would be by setting the AccessProfileID in Employee object, something like this:

```
using (var ds = new DSEntities())
                {
                    Employee e = new Employee();
                    e.AccessProfileId = ds.AccessProfiles.First().Id;
                    ds.Employees.Add(e);
                    ds.SaveChanges();
                }
```

As for why does ef creates new Profile when you execute the code from your example, it has to do something with how it handles graphs. Since Employee object has EntityState.Added I guess it transfers it self to child objects as well. For more info [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) a post from Julie Lerman on very same topic.